# Issue on pushing complex data attributes into one array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am working on the demo below. How can I load all of data in the age attributes into one array, so it looks like this?

```
 out = [48,14,139,49,15,135,51,15,140,49,15,135,51,15,140,52,16,141]
```

```js
let agesindx =[];
$(".box").each(function(){
    //agesindx.push($(this).data('ages').split(','));
    agesindx.push($(this).data('ages'));
  });
 console.log(agesindx);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" data-ages="[48, 14, 139]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[49,15,135],[51,15,140]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[49,15,135],[51,15,140],[52,16,141]"></div>
```

Comment: `data-ages` should be `"[[49,15,135],[51,15,140]]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `JSON.parse` to parse your array from the string.
Then you'll get an array inside a array and so on. So at end you can do `join` and `split` that will give you a single array.

```js
let agesindx =[];
$(".box").each(function(){
    //agesindx.push($(this).data('ages').split(','));
    let x = JSON.parse('['+$(this).data('ages')+']');
    // console.log(JSON.parse('['+$(this).data('ages')+']'));
    agesindx.push(x);
  });
  
 console.log(agesindx.join().split(',') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" data-ages="[48, 14, 139]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[49,15,135],[51,15,140]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[49,15,135],[51,15,140],[52,16,141]"></div>
```

Comment: Close. I think the OP wants the strings converted to numbers.

Comment: OP can convert these later, if he/she needs them as number: `console.log(agesindx.join().split(',').map(i => +i));`

Answer (score 2):

`data-ages` should be an array of arrays like `data-ages="[[48, 14, 139]]"`

Use [`flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to get a concatenated sub-array elements

```js
let agesindx = [];
$(".box").each(function() {
  agesindx.push($(this).data('ages'));
});
console.log(agesindx.flat());
console.log(agesindx.flat(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" data-ages="[[48, 14, 139]]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[[49,15,135],[51,15,140]]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[[49,15,135],[51,15,140],[52,16,141]]"></div>
```

**OR**

using `JSON.parse()`

```js
let agesindx = [];
$(".box").each(function() {
  agesindx.push(JSON.parse('[' + $(this).data('ages').toString() + ']'));
});
console.log(agesindx);
console.log(agesindx.flat(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" data-ages="[48, 14, 139]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[49,15,135],[51,15,140]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[49,15,135],[51,15,140],[52,16,141]"></div>
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the array flattened slightly further.. to 1D.

Comment: Thanks Aswin, this good but I am getting the data from database in that format!

Comment: @MonaCoder You can use a `JSON.parse` method

Answer (score 1):

If you have proper arrays in your `data-ages` attribute like `[[49,15,135],[51,15,140]]` you can get an *array of arrays* using `map()` function on the `box` element list. Then you can use `$.map` to flatten it - see demo below:

```js
let result = $.map($(".box").map(function() {
  return $(this).data('ages');
}).get(), function(e) {
  return e;
});
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" data-ages="[48, 14, 139]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[[49,15,135],[51,15,140]]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[[49,15,135],[51,15,140],[52,16,141]]"></div>
```

Shortened in ES6:

```js
let result = $.map($(".box").map((idx, el) => $(el).data('ages')).get(), e => e);
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" data-ages="[48, 14, 139]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[[49,15,135],[51,15,140]]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[[49,15,135],[51,15,140],[52,16,141]]"></div>
```

Comment: @MonaCoder adding on to the other answers, see another option if you have proper arrays in your data attribute...

Comment: And, fwiw (I may be stating the obvious but...), the code snippet shown here *also* works when the data of the first element is also structured as a 2-D array: `data-ages="[[48, 14, 139]]"` (i.e., double brackets on the end)

Answer (score 0):

`push` was not adding the individual integers to the array because the latter two data ages were strings. You can use regex to extract just the digits and form an array with `match`, push to `agesindx`, then flatten the resulting nested array at the end.

```js
let agesindx =[];
$(".box").each(function(){
    let ages = String($(this).data('ages')).match(/\d+/g);
    agesindx.push(ages);
});
console.log(agesindx.flat());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" data-ages="[48, 14, 139]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[49,15,135],[51,15,140]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[49,15,135],[51,15,140],[52,16,141]"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well You can use `JSON.parse` to get data as array and then to concat use `concat` like here : [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10865042/9501353)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var dataList = $(".box").map(function() {
    return JSON.parse('['+ $(this).data("ages")+']');
  }).get();
  
  var merged = [].concat.apply([], dataList);
  console.log(merged);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" data-ages="[48, 14, 139]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[49,15,135],[51,15,140]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[49,15,135],[51,15,140],[52,16,141]"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code solves the OP's question exactly as asked, in the output format shown, without requiring modification to the html data attributes:

```js
let agesindx =[];
$(".box").each(function(){
    var tmpArr = $(this).data('ages')
    if( typeof tmpArr == 'string' )
     tmpArr = JSON.parse(tmpArr.replace(/\]\,\[/g, ','));
    agesindx = agesindx.concat(tmpArr); 
  });
 console.log(agesindx)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-ages="[48, 14, 139]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[49,15,135],[51,15,140]"></div>
<div class="box" data-ages="[49,15,135],[51,15,140],[52,16,141]"></div>
```

If, however, the data type consistency could be ensured to the same for each element, the code could probably be better at flattening it (re: kukkuz's answer).